# React Bootstrap Navbar contents not filling the width of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Total web dev noob here. Just integrated Bootstrap for the first time, and I'm using a set of Navbars gotten off this link : https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

I've noticed that, while the style is correct and everything looks normal, the text content of the Navbar is not filling the entire width of the Bar. picture shown below

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Navbar File code extract

```
class Navsucks extends Component {
  // componentDidMount() {
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark" >
  <Container>
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="me-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <Nav>
      <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
        Dank memes
      </Nav.Link>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Container>
</Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js code extract

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { posty: []}
  
  componentDidMount() {
    
  }

  render() {

    return (
      
      <div className="App">   
        <Navsucks> </Navsucks>
        <header className="App-header">
          <Texts>  asdasd </Texts>
        </header>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I really just want the left and right halves of the text to be hugging the screen edges. Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The ```container``` in bootstrap already has  a default margin applied to it. Try removing container and see if it works for you.......

Comment: You can also try `m-0` or `p-0` and `no-gutters` classes to remove margin and padding

Comment: happy to help @cshermans

Answer (score 0):

you might getting this problem because you are using wrong container class,
use

```
container class name "  className='fluid-container'  "
```

this worked for me!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34767634)